# Site failing randomly - could it be Cloudflare or something weird in the JS?

Tags: javascript, html5, problem

I've been working on a simple site that uses javascript to fade through some fullscreen background images as well as some other simple animations.

I've tested the site on Chrome, Safari, FF and Opera on OSX, IE8+ on Win7 and Chrome & FF on Ubuntu and everything looks as I'd expect it to. However, I've had reports of the site failing to load (stops at the stage where the background fades up) on Safari and Chrome on OSX and Win. I can't replicate this on any setup so I'm finding it impossible to troubleshoot. Google's instant preview shows the site fine as does most of the options at browsershots.org so I'm really scratching my head.

I'm running the site's traffic through Cloudflare and I'm wondering whether anyone can see (or knows from other sites) why Cloudflare might be mangling the JS or causing a problem somehow (I don't get any errors in the JS error console).
Of course, if you can replicate the problem on your machine and can suggest an area to look at that would be amazing but I'm hoping that, like me, you don't see any problem with the site!

Here's the site: http://www.bighornrevelstoke.com

Thanks,
James

UPDATE: I am very grateful to those of you who have taken the time to made suggestions below but because of my poor *'n00b'* reputation I'm unable to upvote any of the suggestions to show it. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't have minification turned on in Cloudflare as this can cause all sorts of problems. In addition, I do believe there was at least one other setting in there that could cause js errors however as I deleted my account a few weeks ago due to similar issues I can't confirm this...

Comment: Thanks Chris. I'd seen others with Cloudflare minifaction issues so think I've turned that off and replaced the JS (and CSS) with static minified versions. I'll double check though since I've been going round in circles on this and might have made a mistake. Thanks.

Comment: UPDATE: Yes, minification is turned off on Cloudflare.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a minification isue. I believe that this is likely a Rocket Loader issue on the site, so turning this off should fix it (Rocket Loader can impact some JavaScript and jQuery).

Comment: Thanks @damoncloudflare . I've just re-checked the settings in Cloudflare and Rocketloader hasn't been turned on. My main motivation for using CF was threat control so all the minification/optimisation stuff was something I didn't turn on after hearing about people experiencing a couple of issues.
If you have any other ideas or ways to troubleshoot the site that would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [Adobe Browser Lab](https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/features.html) to replicate the problem. If you still can't figure out the problem (You should be able to find out which browsers on which OS's are the problem), then answer back here with your results.

Comment: Hi @Christopher thanks for the top-tip about Browser Lab. I hadn't used it before - I test on local virtual machines of the OS/browsers I target. Browser Lab seems to be a great tool and perfect for sending to clients though! Unfortunately, in Browser Lab all the browsers I'm targeting show the site rendering as I'd expect.
The issues do seem to be reported on OS/browser combos that work (I've looked at analytics and page views/time on site are all OK for those specific browser/OS). Sadly, I can't simply say to the client "it's that person's browser" any more! Lots more head scratching here.

Comment: Try going to JSLint.com and test all your JS to eliminate your code as the problem. It could be specific user setting to disallow JavaScript... some people living in ancient times have had that set for 10 years!

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @Christopher . The JSLint.com website is a bit tricky to use for a site with lots of scripts but I installed this Chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jllekaioicnhoinolncnmofahonmmaio and it's really helpful. No solution yet but perhaps I'm heading in the right direction with this (will keep digging). Sadly, I'm sure it's not users having JS turned off although it would be nice if it were that simple!

Comment: From my experience, as long as you're not using Microsoft products, it's usually something simple. Key word there though, usually. Though if the solution is still elusive, and there is probable cause for erroneous JavaScript, you could hit up StackOverflow with your coding.